# Multiple redux stores in single component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have been entered into react project which uses multiple redux stores.

There many kind of interfaces: tabs, context, popups and other. And architect of this project decide to split this store to make this project more faster.I cant change architecture, and have to work as it does.

And sometimes I encounter situations, when component needs subcribing to 3 stores. And It's terrible pain, because first comes from provider, second from props component

```js
        const { someProps } = this.props;

        return (
                <Provider store={SomeStore}>
                    <Route  <Component props={someProps} />
                </Provider>
        )
```

and third from `State = { store.subsribe }`.

```js
this.state = Store.getState();
Store.subscribe(() => this.setState(Store.getState()));
```

Is it there any possibility to merge multiple stores into one component in a single style?

Comment: Why do you need 3 different stores?
What is wrong with one store, multipile reducers as redux wish you to use?

Comment: Do you have any performance issues or need for such isolation? Please refer to  https://redux.js.org/docs/faq/StoreSetup.html for more info. Could your provide more of the backstory related to this issue ?

Comment: There many kind of interfaces: tabs, context, popups and other. And architactor of this project decide to split this store into diferents to make this project more faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create some kind of Facade or Proxy - basically HOC that will encapsulate all changes and respond to changes either in props, or in store or elsewhere.

I think you can make it similar to Redux store, where main object has properties that represent different data sources/states, that are created by different reducers.

Inside your `Component` you could pass state further down with

1. props change
2. state provided by Provider update
3. react on reactive data source changes

If you work in some isolated area - you can wrap it with this HOC and pass down all data merged from all data sources as prop e.g. called `store`.

Comment: Okey. 
So I have to create HOC with to arguments(wrappedComponents, nameOfStore), which has access to all stores. And there  is
this.state = nameOfStore.getState();
nameOfStore.subscribe(() => this.setState(nameOfStore.getState()));

And return  <wrappedComponents data={this.state}/>

And then wrap component several time with multiple HOC stores?

Comment: as I understand - yes, as you need to plug it into to data sources